# How to re-order a bar graph

Tags: graph, stata

I generated a bar graph for different type of exercise by retirement status. However, the graph is ordered by the retirement status (retired or not retired)

I would like to order the graph by the type of exercise, so that for each type of exercise the retirement status is grouped together.

An example using Stata's toy `auto` dataset can be found below:

```
sysuse auto, clear
graph bar turn mpg gear_ratio, over(foreign)
```

[image]

In this example, I would like the car type to be grouped together for each automobile attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The `reshape` command is a good way to get the data into the format you want:

```
sysuse auto, clear

local my_yvars "turn mpg gear_ratio"
local my_cat_var "foreign"

/* Store variable labels to relabel the variables below */

local labels ""
foreach var of varlist `my_yvars' {
    local `var': variable label `var'
    local labels `"`labels' ("`var'" = "``var''")"'
}

collapse (mean) `my_yvars', by(`my_cat_var')
rename (`my_yvars') (y=)
reshape long y, i(`my_cat_var') j(variable) string

strrec variable `labels', replace
graph bar y , over(`my_cat_var') over(variable) asyvars
```

[image]

Note that `strrec` is a *community-contributed* command, which can be installed from SSC:

```
ssc install strrec
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @NickCox's suggestion, one can also use the *community-contributed* command `statplot`.

The code below generates the equivalent graph in one line:

```
sysuse auto, clear 
statplot gear_ratio mpg turn, over(foreign) vertical asyvars
```

[image]

To use `statplot` first install it by typing the following from Stata's command prompt:

```
ssc install statplot
```